# Caching Lazy Eager Loading Queries in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

How do I cache the lazy eager loading queries based on the model relationships. For example -

```
$books = App\Book::all();

$books->load('author', 'publisher');
```

I can cache the first query with something like this

```
$books = Cache::remember('allbooks', 60, function() {
             return App\Book::all();
         });
```

How do I cache the second query?

If there is no direct way, please suggest any workaround, possibly with a sample code.

**Update:** I need the second query to be executed separately so I can clear these two cache keys separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the query builder `with` method:

```
$books = App\Book::with(['author','publisher'])->get();
```

Or simply do the additional load inside the cache callable:

```
$books = Cache::remember('allbooks', 60, function() {
     return App\Book::all()->load('author', 'publisher');
});
```

**Update**: to keep the caches separated you need two variables, like this:

```
$books = Cache::remember('allbooks', 60, function() 
{
     return App\Book::all();
});
$booksAP = Cache::remember('allbooks_ap', 60, function() use ($books)
{
     return $books->load('author', 'publisher');
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to load the relations separately (I should have made that clear in the question). I need it separately so I can invalidate one cache instead of both together. E.g. Post is LikedbyUsers. On every new LIKE, I want to invalidate the cache containing query for LikedbyUsers but keep Post query cache intact.

Comment: Thanks. It's almost correct but instead of $booksAP assignment in the second function, assign it to $books so the relationship keeps working. Otherwise I would need to pass $booksAP to my views.